# How to mock io.vertx.ext.jdbc.JDBCClient using any mocking frameworks

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx-httpclient, vertx-verticle

I would like to mock `io.vertx.ext.jdbc.JDBCClient` to unit-test the below `verticle` code:

```java
class A {

    private final Helper help = new Helper();

    public JsonObject checkEmailAvailability(String email, JDBCClient jdbc) throws SignUpException {
        JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
        jdbc.getConnection(conn -> help.startTx(conn.result(), beginTans -> {
            JsonArray emailParams = null;
            emailParams = new JsonArray().add(email);
            System.out.println(email);
            help.queryWithParams(conn.result(), SQL_SELECT_USER_EMAIL, emailParams, res -> {
                if (res.getNumRows() >= 1) {
                    result.put("message", "Email already registered");
                }
            });
        }));
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Mockito` to mock your `jdbc` behavior. Let's say you want to test how you verticle behave when `res` returns one row.

Mock your `jdbc`:

```
jdbc = Mockito.mock(JDBCClient.class);
```

Then you have to mock a `ResultSet` object:

```
ResultSet res = Mockito.mock(ResultSet.class);
Mockito.when(res.getNumRows()).thenReturn(1);
```

Then you have to mock the `AsyncResult` object who is in charge to return `res`:

```
AsyncResult<ResultSet> asyncResultResultSet = Mockito.mock(AsyncResult.class);
Mockito.when(asyncResultResultSet.succeeded()).thenReturn(true);
Mockito.when(asyncResultResultSet.result()).thenReturn(res);
```

Then you have to mock the `SQLConnection` object who is in charge to return `asyncResultResultSet`. Use `Answer` to grab the handler and force it to return your mock:

```
SQLConnection sqlConnection = Mockito.mock(SQLConnection.class);
Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<AsyncResult<ResultSet>>() {
  @Override
  public AsyncResult<ResultSet> answer(InvocationOnMock arg0) throws Throwable {
    ((Handler<AsyncResult<ResultSet>>) arg0.getArgument(2)).handle(asyncResultResultSet);
    return null;
  }
}).when(sqlConnection).queryWithParams(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
```

Then you have to mock the `AsyncResult` object who is in charge to return the `sqlConnection`. Again, `Answer` helps:

```
AsyncResult<SQLConnection> sqlConnectionResult = Mockito.mock(AsyncResult.class);
Mockito.when(sqlConnectionResult.succeeded()).thenReturn(true);
Mockito.when(sqlConnectionResult.result()).thenReturn(sqlConnection);
Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<AsyncResult<SQLConnection>>() {
  @Override
  public AsyncResult<SQLConnection> answer(InvocationOnMock arg0) throws Throwable {
    ((Handler<AsyncResult<SQLConnection>>) arg0.getArgument(0)).handle(sqlConnectionResult);
    return null;
  }
}).when(jdbc).getConnection(Mockito.any());
```

Here you are. It is a bunch of code but you can mock multiple `ResultSet` object and use them with the `asyncResultResultSet` by chaining multiple `thenReturn`:

```
Mockito.when(asyncResultResultSet.result()).thenReturn(res1).thenReturn(res2) ...;
```

Try not to test `vertx.io`.

Here is my complete [solution](https://github.com/fpezzati/mockvertx/blob/master/src/test/java/edu/pezzati/mockvertx/MariaDbPersistenceTest.java) if you want to find dependencies. I also use `Powermock` with `VertxUnit` to run my verticle.

Comment: You should provide full solution explanation pointed with external links and not simple links.

Answer (score 0):

To mock the JDBCClient in vertx using mockito ..add dependency testCompile "io.vertx:vertx-codegen:3.2.1"

Otherwise you will get error as . Cannot mock static